# How to change the font for specific code lines on intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to change font size/style on specific code lines on intellij IDEA without changing the overall settings?

Comment: Hello Michael, which specific lines and how do you select/decide to enlarge/bold these lines ?

Comment: You can't do this in Intellij, or I can say in any IDEs. Enlarge/bold is css property and your java code does not contains any css property, it is saved just as simply text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change font size/style for specific lines, only some formatting settings (right-click on text selection > Show context actions > Adjust code style settings).

You can, however, use [bookmarks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#use_bookmarks) to highlight various parts of code.

1. Change the background of bookmarks under **File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General**:

[image]

2. Set a bookmark on the desired line:

[image]

3. Observe how the line changes color:

[image]

After that you can browse through your bookmarks in the Favorites tool window (`Alt+2`) or the Bookmarks pop-up window (`Shift+F11`):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tried to use the other options in the bookmark settings like Bold or Effects and they don't work. do you know why?

Comment: No problem Michael. Please vote for [IDEA-243053](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243053).